# Do I need to copy-paste stuff form ".gitignore" to ".npmignore"

Tags: npm, gitignore, npmignore

So I was reading [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package).

And I'm a bit confuse how it's works, as I understood it:

If I only have `.gitignore` in my repo npm will use `.gitignore` but If I have both `.gitignore` and `.npmignore` npm will only read `.npmignore`, right? Or it will read both?

Need to know, if it's only reading `.npmignore` I have to copy-paste stuff from `.gitignore` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Or will it read both?

As [mentioned here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package), it will only read the `.npmignore`

> If you want to include something that is excluded by your `.gitignore` file, you can create an *empty* `.npmignore` file to override it.

Although, [Jeff Dickey](https://twitter.com/jdxcode) advocates for: "[For the love of god, don’t use .npmignore](https://medium.com/@jdxcode/for-the-love-of-god-dont-use-npmignore-f93c08909d8d)"

> However, what you probably don’t know is that my little action of adding the npmignore file actually causes `npm` to now consult that file instead of the gitignore files.
> **This is a major issue—I’ve now leaked all my AWS credentials out to the public just by adding this `.npmignore` to hide my test directory**.

> What’s worse is I probably have no idea this happened. `npm publish` doesn’t show the files that were packed (it actually does with npm 6).
> I don’t see the files on the npm registry.

> The only real way to see the files is by adding the package to a project and manually looking inside node_modules.
> I might do that someday out of curiosity and discover my AWS credentials have been sitting out in the open for months.

Solution/safer alternative:

> `npm` supports whitelisting though, just add a files attribute to `package.json` with everything you intend to add to the project.
> Now only the files that are specified in files will be included in the project and your dotfiles will be ignored.

Comment: Let's say I have this `test*` in my `.gitignore` and I have this `test* .github`in `.npmignore`, so I'm fine then? it will not push anything coints `test*` to github and won't publish to npm and also it won't publish `.github` folder to npm, correct?

Comment: also you forgot to paste first link: `As [mentioned here][1], it will read only the .npmignore`

Comment: @Bromer Yes, but do not use npmignore, as explained.

Comment: My opinion of Node's maturity sinks even lower.

Comment: I read that article, author's issue was what he didn't knew what npm ignores `.gitignore` file if there is `.npmignore` file which is stupid from npm. But it doesn't make any sense for me to whitelist files in my user case since only 5-10% of files have to be ignored.